# resolve field function before sort

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

I am creating a graphql server using express, and I have a resolver that can transform my fields as per input from the user query.
The transformer that I am using is returning a function, which is the cause of my issues.

I want to sort my result by some user determined field, but since the field is a function, it won't work.

So the resolver looks like this:

```
const resolver = (req, param) => {
  return {
    history: async input => {
      let size = input.pageSize || 3;
      let start = (input.page || 0) * size;
      let end = start + size;
      let sortField = (input.sort || {}).field || 'timestamp';
      return fs.promises.readFile("./history/blitz.json", "utf8").then(data =>
        JSON.parse(data)
          .slice(start, end)
          .map(job => historyTransformer(job))
          .sort((a,b) => a[sortField] > b[sortField] ? 1 : a[sortField] < b[sortField] ? -1 : 0)
      );
    }
  };
};
```

and the transformer:

```
const historyTransformer = job => {
  return {
    ...job,
    timestamp: input =>
      dateFormat(job.timestamp, input.format || "mm:hh dd-mm-yyyy")
  };
};
```

I am not sure if I am missing something but is there an easy way of resolving the function call before starting the sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL fields are resolved in a hierarchal manner, such that the `history` field has to resolve before any of its child fields (like `timestamp`) can be resolved. If the child field's resolver transforms the underlying property and your intent is to somehow use that value in the parent resolver (in this case, to do some sorting), that's tricky because you're working against the execution flow.

Because you're working with dates, you should consider whether the format of the field even matters. As a user, if I sort by timestamp, I expect the results to be sorted chronologically. Even if the response is formatted to put the time first, I probably don't want dates with the same times but different years grouped together. Of course, I don't know your business requirements and it still doesn't solve the problem if we're working with something else, like translations, which would cause the same problem.

There's two solutions I can think of:

- Update your schema and lift the `format` argument into the parent field. This is easier to implement, but obviously not as nice as putting the argument on the field it applies to.
- Keep the argument where it is, but [parse the info parameter](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a) passed to the resolver to determine the value of the argument inside the parent resolver. This way, you can keep the argument on the child field, but move the actual formatting logic into the parent resolver.